# How to remove this "symlink" kind of thing inside a repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

[image]

While working with some repositories, in recent commits, I started seeing a link as shown in above image. When I try to open it, it redirects to the same page.

What exactly is this ?. How can we remove it ?.

Comment: Looks like a subrepository.

Comment: That's someone's (GitLab's?) method of displaying a *gitlink*. A gitlink is half a submodule, with the other half being information stored in the `.gitmodules` file. WIthout the other half, a gitlink is pretty useless. With the other half, it means "I want the specified commit": this display shows an abbreviated hash, `a28c9d31`, which presumably is the desired commit in the submodule. We can't see the rest of the submodule information here.

Comment: @torek Thank you for explaining. But what would be the reason it came all of a sudden ?. How to make sure this thing will never come in a commit ?.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing that is creating them. If you pay attention when committing, though, you can spot them: a gitlink has mode `160000`.

Comment: this question should be marked as "answered"

Comment: @torek, I am in fact mirroring the repository to an external repository. I use yml to execute a job that does the mirroring since we have restricted access to external repository.